# 'Internal' Variable through function

Tags: c#, function, global

I am trying to create code for a DLL that will manage, create and return variables to the program using it. I could just not use a DLL but I want my code to be less cluttered and also to save time in "if var == whatever" statements.

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JERK_mgr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // DLL file that makes managing, reading and creating variables easier
            // >>J03L<<
            // v0.0-initial 

            newVar("", "");
            Console.WriteLine(TESTVAR);
        }

        internal static void newVar(string name, object value);
        {
            public const string TESTVAR = "hey it actually worked! :D";

        }
    }
}
```

At this moment in time I don't intend for it to do anything but the following:
 - Be called from Main
 - create a variable that can then be accessed through Main and any other methods.

I am aware that I may be using internal incorrectly here, but it was just an attempt at getting it to work and just used to be public.

What then happens is I get an error at

```
internal static void >>newvar<<(string name, object value)
```

saying it must declare a body, but this isn't my main problem, atleast as far as I know.

I then get an error at

```
internal static void newvar(string name, object value)
>>{<<
```

I also notice that

```
internal static void newVar(string name, object value);
{
    public const string TESTVAR = "hey it actually worked! :D";
>>}<<
```

when hovered over or selected, says it matches up to

```
class Program
{
```

So I ask, how do I have a function that is not the Main function declare a variable that is accessible throughout any other function, including the Main function?

**EDIT1: I think I have found a way to make the variables how I want them, but now I am facing the problem of mismatching curly brackets even though they should match (can be seen at https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LwCP.jpg)**

Comment: You propably wanted a Function Scope variable. I know Native C++ has support for that. .NET unfortunately does not support those. Use simple old static variables instead.

Comment: *So I ask, how do I have a function that is not the Main function declare a variable that is accessible throughout any other function, including the Main function?* Answer: You cannot. A variable declared in a function (method) can only be used within the method.

Comment: After having rad this question three times I still don´t have any clue about what you want to achieve. There are so many errors in your code that it´s hard to find a starting-point for it.

Comment: That's not a mismatch of curlies. You cannot have `public` within a method. It's that simple. Stop writing a novel (application) if you don't know the grammar and rules of a language. And read my previous comment: you cannot declare a variable inside a function and use it outside.

Comment: Removing the public doesn't change the fact that the error still exists

Comment: It is a different error because you are accessing the variable outside the method. If you put `public`, it is a different error.

Comment: Oh okay I thought you meant to remove the public in public static void

Comment: What you can do in your DLL is this: `public class Constants { public const string TESTVAR = "Test"; }`. Then you can access it in your main or anywhere else like this: `Console.Write(Constants.TESTVAR)`. Try that and see if that's what you are after. You can even give your constants more context and do this: `public class Constants { public class Tax rate { public const decimal Provincial = .15m; }}`. Now to access: `Constants.TaxRate.Provincial`

Comment: You should rethink your design. A method is something that **does** something. In your case there´s nothing to do when calling that method. It´s not even clear what the outcome of your method should be. What is the actual **goal** you want to achieve by this attempt? It seems you have a really specific problem which you didn´t write here, so alll we can do is wild guessing.

Answer (score 0):

remove `;` after `(string name, object value)`

and it's a function you can't declare a `public const` value in the function try to move to outside.

```
class Program
{
    public string TESTVAR = "hey it actually worked! :D";
    internal static void newVar(string name, object value)
    {

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //....
    }
}
```

Comment: You certainly can declare a constant value within a function...what you cannot do is declare a `public` constant.

Comment: @KennethK. Thanks

Comment: Removing the semi-colon did not fix the errors mentioned, although it was a good spot so thanks for that. And I don't necessarily need a constant value, it was just an experiment I tried to see if I could get what it is that I want the program to do. It will be impossible to have the variable located outside of the function, as the function needs to create a *new* variable, not edit an existing one. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: You can declare a variable in the function.

Comment: @D-Shih but I then need to access that variable outside of that function

Comment: You can use `public string TESTVAR = "hey it actually worked! :D"; ` instead of `public const string TESTVAR = "hey it actually worked! :D";` in the outer scope then you can access that variable outside of that function

Comment: @D-Shih, ok that might work, but I still run into the problem with the } not matching correctly, when I try to do this inside a function that is inside of the Program class, even if I use public static void

Comment: @J03L You just make your every `{` need to match with `}`  you can see my edit answer

Comment: @D-Shih I know that, but it isnt actually matching for some reason.. It looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/scBYuaH

Comment: Did your `const` value add with `public`?  if yes you can try to remove it.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "add with public" but the error was not fixed after removing it

Answer (score 0):

I think the question you are really asking is "how do I write a function that defines global variables?" If that really is your question then the answer is C# (any many other object oriented languages) won't allow it. (unless maybe you use some twisted kind of reflection code.)

Comment: The sole purpose of the variable is to be accessible through other functions. It doesn't have to be accessible in any other kind of scope, only things like "static void"

Comment: So you want to define a variable with a scope that is less than global scope but also greater than function scope. This still cannot be done in C#. Note that function scope means the scope is limited to the currently executing function. It is not possible to define a variable (even a static variable) that is accessible outside the currently executing function

Comment: @J03L In C# a variable declared inside a function is *only* accessible from within that function's scope.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I have a function that is not the Main function declare a
>   variable that is accessible throughout any other function, including
>   the Main function?

While you can't dynamically create variables, you can do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp29
{
    class Program
    {

        public static dynamic Vars = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

        static void AddorUpdateVar(string name, object value)
        {
            var vd = (IDictionary<string, object>)Vars;
            vd[name] = value;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            AddorUpdateVar("Hello", 213);

            var a1 = Vars.Hello;

            AddorUpdateVar("Hello", "World");

            var a2 = Vars.Hello;

            Vars.Hello = new int[] { 7, 3 };

            var a3 = Vars.Hello;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See update.  You can update for two ways to change a value.

Comment: TryAdd is erroring with no extension method accepting a first argument of type ExpandoObject could be found

Comment: You need to import the namespace that defines that function by adding `using System.Collections.Generic;`.